# Cross Origin issue with accessing external API

Tags: jquery, rest

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get({
                url: "http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races/",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(result){
                    result.results.forEach(function(element) {
                        $("#racebox").append('<option value="'+element.url+'">'+element.name+ ' '+'</option>');
                    });

                    $('#racebox').on('change',function(){
                        var raceChoice = $('#racebox').val();
                        console.log(raceChoice);
                        $.get({
                            url: raceChoice,
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            success: function(result){
                                result.starting_proficiencies.forEach(function(element) {
                                    $("#output").append(element.name);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="racebox">
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>


</body>
```

I am trying to work with an API, I am unable to get past a cross origin issue with the code, I am unsure how to do this because one file is meant to feed the url to the other. It is from a restful API and I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this or getting around the problem. I'd love to see an example if possible, I will be working with a lot of requests feeding from these next urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easy solve this, 
just dont access the api with js

change

```
url: "http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races/",
```

to

```
url: "http://yourowndomain/script",
```

and the script file may be for example php script that fetches the data serverside. so you dont run into crossorigin issues

the script could be as simple as

```
return file_get_contents('http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races/');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this to try and get my code working.

Comment: does that php work with local files too? Like a file directory rather than an email

Comment: sure, it works with local paths too. Dont know what you mean by email, check out the docs